# "Hagahos MaimoniYOS"?

Tags: rambam, books-generally

Is the correct title for the work abbreviated "ה"מ" "*Hagahos Maimoni*" or "*Hagahos Maimoniyos*"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Frankel ed. it is called Hagahos Maimoniyos.

Answer (score 6):

It would seem from this link that it is Hagahos Maimoniyos.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26453&pgnum=49