# What's "מיי׳" short for?

Tags: names, rambam, commentaries, talmud-bavli, acronyms

The *En Mishpat Ner Mitzva* on the *Bavli* (in [the standard edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Shas), anyway) refers to the *Mishne Tora* (*Yad Hachazaka*) as "מיי׳". What is this an abbreviation of? (I have an educated guess ("מיימוני"), but seek a strong argument or good evidence.)

Comment: Maybe it's מי יודע

Comment: Is there any way to know officially without a direct claim by whoever first used the abbreviation?

Comment: note that two of the commentaries on the Rambam are named "הגהות מיימונית" and one named "תשובות  מיימוניות" - http://hebrewbooks.org/39979

Comment: see Sefer Roshei Teivot http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34968&pgnum=167

Comment: Related?: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6860/3

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83707/759

Answer (score 1):

It stand for מיימונידס‎ or מיימוני - Maimonides, i.e. the Rambam. I think they used this because it is the shortest way of referencing the Mishneh Torah.

Comment: How do you know? The OP also guessed this, but he sought "a strong argument or good evidence" to support it.

Comment: Shorter options ... מ"ת ... י"ד